# Change position within a tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I've been working on some code to support young children with their counting.

A rectangle grid with some dots in it is called a tens frame

[image]

The above image is the tens frame for 3.

I am wanting students to count beyond ten, and using images like below to show 2-digit numbers. Note that completed tens frames are shaded to help emphasise that this is the first digit of the number.

[image]

The above image is the tens frame for 23.

Using Daniel's answer below, here is some code that allows numbers to gradually appear in tens frame form: Note the first input in the code is the starting number, the second input is the final number and the third input is the slide that the numbers start changing on.

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\definecolor{titlebg}{RGB}{231, 182, 13}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  pics/full tens/.style={%
    code={%
      \fill[titlebg!20] (0, 0) rectangle (5, 2);
      \draw[titlebg] (0, 0) grid (5, 2);
      \foreach \j in {0, 1}{%
        \foreach \i in {0, ..., 4}{%
          \filldraw[titlebg] (\i +.5, \j +.5) circle (.28);
        }
      }
    }
  },
  pics/tens/.style={%
    code={%
      \tikzmath{%
        integer \erem;
        if #1>5 then {%
          {%
            \draw (0, 0) grid (5, 2);
          };
          for \i in {0, ..., 4}{
            {%
              \filldraw[titlebg] (\i +.5, 1.5) circle (.28);
            };
          };
          \erem = #1 -6;
          for \i in {0, ..., \erem}{%
            {%
              \filldraw[titlebg] (\i +.5, .5) circle (.28);
            };
          };
        } else {%
          \erem = #1 -1;
          if \erem >= 0 then {%
            {%
              \draw (0, 0) grid (5, 2);
            };
            for \i in {0, ..., \erem}{%
              {%
                \filldraw[titlebg] (\i +.5, 1.5) circle (.28);
              };
            };
          };
        };
      }
    }
  },
  pics/counting/.style 2 args={%  number, scale
    code={%
      \tikzmath{%
        integer \N, \fullTens, \rows;
        \rows = #1/50;
        \fullTens = (#1 -\rows*50)/10;
        \N = #1 -\rows*50 -\fullTens*10;
        if \rows>0 then {%
          for \j in {1, ..., \rows}{%
            for \i in {0, ..., 4}{%
              {%
                \path (\i*6*#2, {(-\j +1)*3*#2}) pic[scale=#2] {full tens};
              };
            };
          };
        };
        if \fullTens>0 then {%
          for \i in {1, ..., \fullTens}{%
            {%
              \path ({(\i -1)*6*#2}, -\rows*3*#2) pic[scale=#2] {full tens};
            };
          };
        };
        {%
          \path (\fullTens*6*#2, -\rows*3*#2) pic[scale=#2] {tens=\N};
        };
      }
    }
  }
}

%%%#1 = first number, #2 = last number, #3 = number the counting starts on
\newcommand{\TFCounting}[3]{\begin{tikzpicture}
\only<1-\fpeval{#3-1}>{\path (0, 0) pic {counting={\fpeval{#1}}{.35}}};
  \foreach \x in {#3,...,\fpeval{#3+#2-#1-1}} \only<\x>{\path (0, 0) pic {counting={\fpeval{#1-#3+1+\x}}{.35}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}


\begin{frame}
\TFCounting{60}{65}{3}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note that the code

```
\TFCounting{60}{65}{3}
```

Gives a tens frame representation of 60 until slide 3 where it starts counting on to 65 frame by frame.

The question is now answered, thank you Daniel!

With thanks,
Wendy

Comment: Hi Wendy!  Do you really need the result in a single command?  Would you be happy if, say 73, is obtained using two commands?  Something like  1) `\full5tens` 2) `\tensFor{23}`.

Comment: This could work. The most important thing is that I can show students how to count from say 70 to 73 and that I can produce multiple slides, say slide 1-4 showing 70, slide 5 showing 71, slide 6 showing 72 and slide 7 showing 73. Thanks for your query :)

Comment: @WendyTaylor  Not related to your question, but what is the age of these kids?

Comment: 5 years old, just learning to count beyond 10 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

I created a `pic` object called `counting` which takes two arguments, the number and the scale.  In the figure you can see the result for 124.  It uses the library `math` and two other `pic` objects, `tens` and `full tens`.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\definecolor{titlebg}{RGB}{231, 182, 13}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  pics/full tens/.style={%
    code={%
      \fill[titlebg!20] (0, 0) rectangle (5, 2);
      \draw[titlebg] (0, 0) grid (5, 2);
      \foreach \j in {0, 1}{%
        \foreach \i in {0, ..., 4}{%
          \filldraw[titlebg] (\i +.5, \j +.5) circle (.28);
        }
      }
    }
  },
  pics/tens/.style={%
    code={%
      \tikzmath{%
        integer \erem;
        if #1>5 then {%
          {%
            \draw (0, 0) grid (5, 2);
          };
          for \i in {0, ..., 4}{
            {%
              \filldraw[titlebg] (\i +.5, 1.5) circle (.28);
            };
          };
          \erem = #1 -6;
          for \i in {0, ..., \erem}{%
            {%
              \filldraw[titlebg] (\i +.5, .5) circle (.28);
            };
          };
        } else {%
          \erem = #1 -1;
          if \erem >= 0 then {%
            {%
              \draw (0, 0) grid (5, 2);
            };
            for \i in {0, ..., \erem}{%
              {%
                \filldraw[titlebg] (\i +.5, 1.5) circle (.28);
              };
            };
          };
        };
      }
    }
  },
  pics/counting/.style 2 args={%  number, scale
    code={%
      \tikzmath{%
        integer \N, \fullTens, \rows;
        \rows = #1/50;
        \fullTens = (#1 -\rows*50)/10;
        \N = #1 -\rows*50 -\fullTens*10;
        if \rows>0 then {%
          for \j in {1, ..., \rows}{%
            for \i in {0, ..., 4}{%
              {%
                \path (\i*6*#2, {(-\j +1)*3*#2}) pic[scale=#2] {full tens};
              };
            };
          };
        };
        if \fullTens>0 then {%
          for \i in {1, ..., \fullTens}{%
            {%
              \path ({(\i -1)*6*#2}, -\rows*3*#2) pic[scale=#2] {full tens};
            };
          };
        };
        {%
          \path (\fullTens*6*#2, -\rows*3*#2) pic[scale=#2] {tens=\N};
        };
      }
    }
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path (0, 3) node[right, scale=2] {124 with \texttt{scale=0.75}};
  \path (0, 0) pic {counting={123}{.75}};
  
  \begin{scope}[yshift=-7.5cm]
    \path (0, 0) node[right, scale=2] {using \texttt{tens=8}:}
    (6, -1) pic {tens=8};
  \end{scope}
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on this, Daniel. This works brilliantly for numbers 60 and greater. This is a huge help! Is it possible to adjust the code so it can create values in the 50s, or even less than 50? Say 23?

Comment: I modified the code; it works now, I think.  I was too confident and didn't test it thoroughly!

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!! I've used your code to define a set of slides that shows the numbers gradually growing. It's beautiful! However, I'm getting an error message (included in my edited question). Do you know how I might fix this? Thanks again :)

Comment: I found my error, I was missing a f in front of the peval. Sorry!

Comment: I'm glad you can use it!

Answer (score 0):

You might find this useful.  It provides a PDF containing images for one through ten.  Just use `\includegraphics[page=10]{filename}` (for example).  All the work is precomputed.  You can create a border around each image using [inner sep].

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{titlebg}{RGB}{231, 182, 13}

\newsavebox{\digit}
\savebox\digit{\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]{\filldraw[color=titlebg] circle (.28);}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes, row sep=-.4pt, column sep=-.4pt, inner sep=0pt,
  nodes={minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, draw=black}]{
  \usebox\digit & \null & \null & \null & \null \\
  \null & \null & \null & \null & \null \\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes, row sep=-.4pt, column sep=-.4pt, inner sep=0pt,
  nodes={minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, draw=black}]{
  \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \null & \null & \null \\
  \null & \null & \null & \null & \null \\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes, row sep=-.4pt, column sep=-.4pt, inner sep=0pt,
  nodes={minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, draw=black}]{
  \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \null & \null \\
  \null & \null & \null & \null & \null \\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes, row sep=-.4pt, column sep=-.4pt, inner sep=0pt,
  nodes={minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, draw=black}]{
  \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \null \\
  \null & \null & \null & \null & \null \\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes, row sep=-.4pt, column sep=-.4pt, inner sep=0pt,
  nodes={minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, draw=black}]{
  \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit \\
  \null & \null & \null & \null & \null \\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes, row sep=-.4pt, column sep=-.4pt, inner sep=0pt,
  nodes={minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, draw=black}]{
  \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit \\
  \usebox\digit & \null & \null & \null & \null \\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes, row sep=-.4pt, column sep=-.4pt, inner sep=0pt,
  nodes={minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, draw=black}]{
  \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit \\
  \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \null & \null & \null \\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes, row sep=-.4pt, column sep=-.4pt, inner sep=0pt,
  nodes={minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, draw=black}]{
  \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit \\
  \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \null & \null \\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes, row sep=-.4pt, column sep=-.4pt, inner sep=0pt,
  nodes={minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, draw=black}]{
  \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit \\
  \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \null \\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes, row sep=-.4pt, column sep=-.4pt, inner sep=0pt,
  nodes={minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, draw=titlebg, fill=titlebg!20}]{
  \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit \\
  \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit & \usebox\digit \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```